# Can VS Code extensions pollute my system installs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I noticed that one of the VS Code extensions — [Todo Tree](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.todo-tree) — relies on `ripgrep`.

That left me wondering: Are extensions allowed to run scripts which can have side-effects beyond the `~/.vscode/extensions` directory?

I like to install most apps through Flatpak/AppImage for cleaner removal (should I have to), but VS Code is one app which I had to install through the default methods so that I can share installed binaries for compilers etc more easily. So I’m more concerned about this.

Comment: I don’t use VS Code but in general all different kind of languages and package systems install stuff locally like this and — unless the system code looks for that code — it’s a non issue.

Comment: This is a question for the VSCode developers. Have you researched the VSCode plugin framework?

Comment: If this question is most appropriate for VSCode developers, I'd like to move it to stackoverflow instead. It seems that on their github issues, they say questions should be asked on SO: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose